# putting image on background from input file url

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<script>
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var img=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    document.getElementById('Display1').style.backgroundImage= url(img);
};
</script>
```

```
<div class="HM1EI" id="Display1">
 <button type="button" class="_1q_T1">
  <label>
   <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file1"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;">
    Add Media
  </label>

</button>
</div>
```

I can't Upload the file on the background which I get from input type file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the background url correctly you should do it like this

```
document.getElementById('Display1').style.backgroundImage = `url('img_tree.png')`;
```

Put (url) in string

Comment: Use a templating string to dynamically create url string